# Put text from TextBox with a Button into a ListView

Tags: c#, windows, listview, textbox

I have two controls

- a `FormBox` with a `Button` and a `TextBox`
- a `FormView` with a `ListView`

I want to send the text from the textbox from `FormBox` to the `FormView` when I click the button.

Comment: I took the liberty of modifying your question which (at least to me) reads more clearly. If you feel that I have messed it up you can click the "edited x seconds/minutes ago" and choose `rollback` from the first revision.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to this request...

Maybe the simplest one is to pass to `FormBox` a reference to the existing instance of `FormView` (e.g. in FormBox constructor)... then you have to set `Public` as `Modifiers` in your ListView object (you can do it through form designer in Visual Studio, selecting your ListView object and then editing its properties).

Finally write something like:

```
myFormView.myListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(myTextBox.Text));
```

in your button click event handler.

This is not the best solution from the stylistic point of view, but maybe it's the simplest.

Accept this answer if it answers your question.

Comment: @Robin8521: why have you unaccepted my answer today? Can I know?

Answer (score 0):

Forms are classes. Easy way is to define constructor for the second form that takes string as input. Now in the first form (where you have the button), instantiate the second form in button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm=new Form2(textBox1.Text);
    //...
}
```

Now in the second form you get this text value as a string in the constructor. Hold this value in a string variable (for example: `listVal`) and add this value to the list:

```
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(listVal); 
    listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
```

This is a way you can solve your problem. Please provide your own code work while asking any question.